# Autofac 3.0 does not run on Mono

Tags: .net, mono, autofac

I have been trying to get Autofac 3.0.1 working on Mono, but have so far been unsuccessful. When I try to run an application that references Autofac 3.0.1 on Mono 3.0.5, I get the following exception:

```
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0x14ce2c70] -> /opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll[0x14ce1ec0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0x14ce2c70] added to domain ConsoleApplication1.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'ConsoleApplication1.exe'.
Mono: Image addref ConsoleApplication1[0x14d20230] -> /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/ConsoleApplication1.exe[0x14d1f4a0]: 2
Mono: Assembly ConsoleApplication1[0x14d20230] added to domain ConsoleApplication1.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'ConsoleApplication1.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'ConsoleApplication1.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref ConsoleApplication1[0x14d20230] -> mscorlib[0x14ce2c70]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Autofac[0x14d269b0] -> /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll[0x14d25c40]: 2
Mono: Assembly Autofac[0x14d269b0] added to domain ConsoleApplication1.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref ConsoleApplication1[0x14d20230] -> Autofac[0x14d269b0]: 2
Mono: The request to load the retargetable assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to mscorlib v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Autofac[0x14d269b0] -> mscorlib[0x14ce2c70]: 3
Mono: The request to load the retargetable assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to System.Core v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__7cec85d7bea7798e/System.Core.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/System.Core.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/System.Core.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__7cec85d7bea7798e/System.Core.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/System.Core.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/System.Core.exe'.
Mono: The following assembly referenced from /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   System.Core    (assemblyref_index=1)
     Version:    2.0.5.0
     Public Key: 7cec85d7bea7798e
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/).

Mono: Failed to load assembly Autofac[0x14d269b0]

Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies.
Missing method .ctor in assembly /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll mtoken: 0x0a000015
Hello!
Mono: Unloading domain ConsoleApplication1.exe[0x2aaaab6f1cc0], assembly mscorlib[0x14ce2c70], ref_count=3
Mono: Unloading domain ConsoleApplication1.exe[0x2aaaab6f1cc0], assembly ConsoleApplication1[0x14d20230], ref_count=1
Mono: Unloading assembly ConsoleApplication1 [0x14d20230].
Mono: Unloading image /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/ConsoleApplication1.exe [0x14d1f4a0].
Mono: Unloading domain ConsoleApplication1.exe[0x2aaaab6f1cc0], assembly Autofac[0x14d269b0], ref_count=1
Mono: Unloading assembly Autofac [0x14d269b0].
Mono: Unloading image /var/www/sites/erik/monoconsole/Autofac.dll [0x14d25c40].
Mono: Unloading assembly mscorlib [0x14ce2c70].
Mono: Unloading image /opt/mono-3.0.5/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll [0x14ce1ec0].
```

There are several things to note. First, it appears that System.Core 2.0.5.0 could not be loaded. Could this be due to Autofac 3.0.1 being a portable class library?

This problem also results in the second issue, where there is a Missing method .ctor in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute. I have found some information about this problem, and it appears that this problem is due to the ExtensionAttribute class being moved from one DLL to another: http://www.lextm.com/2013/02/how-to-use-nuget-on-mono-part-iv.html

This problem can be reproduced as follows (see https://gist.github.com/ErikSchierboom/5047101):

1. Create a .NET 4.0 console application
2. Add a reference to Autofac 3.0.1 (e.g. through NuGet)
3. Create an instance of the `ContainerBuilder` class
4. Build the console application
5. Run the console application under Mono

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I did some more testing and created a .NET 4.0 class library version of the Autofac.Core project. Now when I build this version and link my test project to this version of Autofac.dll (which is a .NET 4.0 library instead of a portable class library), everything works fine under Mono. Does Mono not correctly support portable class libraries?

Comment: After some further deep-diving into the subject matter, it turns out that the problem is not the portable class library by itself. It is the combination of a portable class library and extension methods. The Autofac library defines extension methods, which causes Mono 3.0.5 to fail. I have a repro of this problem here: https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/monoportableclasslibraryextensionmethod

Comment: Could you please drop the repro into [Mono Bugzilla](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi) as well?

Comment: Done: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a repro of this problem at:
https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/monoportableclasslibraryextensionmethod It
contains two console applications and two portable class libraries. One
portable class library defines a method as an extension method and the other
does not. One console application uses the extension method version, and the
other does not. To verify the problem, run both console applications on a Mono
3.0.5 environment. The one that uses the extension method version will crash
and the other will not.

Mono 3.0.12 has full PCL functionality and prevents this error from happening: http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0#New_in_Mono_3.0.12

Comment: It would be great if you could add a bug to the issue list (although I can't promise I can fix this one). https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/list

Comment: Alex, I created the following bug: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=417&thanks=417&ts=1363806624

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, have you found a workaround for the problem? It seems like the project you are linking is only to test if the problem occurs. Isn't ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The workaround is to use newer versions of mono, which corrected this issue.